# How do you view the auto generated designer code for c# controls in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Right now for my User Controls I right click the control in the Solution Explorer and then choose 'View Code'. Then, in the top right corner where all the class's elements are enumerated in a dropdown box, I choose the grey'd out constructor and this brings me to the auto generated .designer.cs file that I'm looking for.

I feel like this is a really round-about way of doing it and it doesn't sit well with me. Am I supposed to be doing a better job of avoiding editing these files? Are they hard to get to on purpose or did I just clearly miss something simple in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you want to edit these files? It's fine to view them but I'd avoid editing them.

Comment: Because sometimes I programmatically set the contents of GUI controls as enumerating drop down boxes manually is a pain and using the built-in collection  in Visual Studio is still unknown to me currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should quite simply be able to use the treeview of the Solution Explorer to expand the user control items and see the code-behind and designer files.

This is curious, so I wonder what *kind* of user control (any particular project type)?

As for avoidance of editing these auto-generated files: yes, you should be weary in doing so, and avoid it wherever possible. Your changes are going to disappear if the code is ever regenerated (not *that* likely for user controls, I suppose), and the developers of the tool that generated it can't vouch for it working as it should if edited.

There are times when you do want to edit these kinds of files, however. So use your own judgement to evaluate the value of doing so. I find myself dipping into the DBML designer files often enough to delete the default constructor which conflicts with my own in the partial definition, haven't found another way to do what I want. Such is the situation.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing because I had simply just never clicked the little carrot on the side of the control in the Solution Explorer. Apparently it was something simple all along I was missing, thanks :)

These kinds of things happen when you get thrust into new environments without training :P

Answer (score 1):

Editing autogenerated code is never a good idea. The reason being that the code can be generated at any time and your changes will be lost. If you really, REALLY need to edit the code, you should be doing so using partial classes. But 95% of the time you shouldn't need to edit autogenerated code in the first place. What exactly is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: my changes aren't getting lost though. i'm making the changes in the constructor inside of the auto generated form only and not inside the InitializeComponent() function. How else do I add code to the constructor without using the autogenerated file?

Comment: Read up on partial classes.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it: Let's say you have a **Label** control called `Label1`.

If it is never actually used in your code, place some code that uses it somewhere in one of your methods:

```
private void Test() {
  Label1.Text = null;
}
```

Now, put your Cursor over the `Label1` control and press <kbd>F12</kbd>. This will take you to the definition of `Label1`

Hope that helps!

Comment: The point is, just select the control, method, or class name and hit `F12`